# How to Sample Adobe Analytics (Omniture) Data

Tags: adobe, sampling, adobe-analytics

I can't find anything on the web about how to sample Adobe Analytics data? I need to integrate Adobe Analytics into a new website with a ton of traffic so the stakeholders want to sample the data to avoid exorbitant server calls. I'm using DTM but not sure if that will help or be a non-factor? Can anyone either point me to some documentation or give me some direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adobe Analytics does not have any built-in method for sampling data, neither on their end nor in the js code.

DTM doesn't offer anything like this either. It doesn't have any (exposed) mechanisms in place to evaluate *all* requests made to a given property (container); any rules that extend state beyond "hit" scope are cookie based.

Adobe Target does offer ability to output code based on % of traffic so you can achieve sampling this way, but really, you're just trading one server call cost for another.

Basically, your only solution would be to create your own server-side framework for conditionally outputting the Adobe Analytics (or DTM) tag, to achieve sampling with Adobe Analytics.

**Update:**

*@MichaelJohns comment below:*

> We have a file that we use as a boot strap file to serve the DTM file.
>   What I think we are going to do is use some JS logic and cookies
>   around that to determine if a visitor should be served the DTM code.

Okay, well maybe i'm misunderstanding what your goal here is (*but I don't think I am*) but that's not going to work.

For example, if you only want to output tracking for 50% of visitors, how would you use javascript and cookies alone to achieve this? In order to know that you are only filtering 50%, you need to know the total # of people in play. By itself, javascript and cookies only know about ONE browser, ONE person. It has no way of knowing anything about those other 99 people unless you have some sort of shared state between all of them, like keeping track of a count in a database server-side.

The best you can do solely with javascript and cookies is that you can basically flip a coin. In this example of 50%, basically you'd pick a random # between 1 and 100 and lower half gets no tracking, higher half gets tracking.

The problem with this is that it is possible for the pendulum to swing 100% one way or the other. It is the same principle as flipping a coin 100 times in a row: it is entirely possible that it can land on tails all 100 times.

In theory, the trend over time should show an overall average of 50/50, but this has a major flaw in that you may go one month with a ton of traffic, another month with few. Or you could have a week with very little traffic followed by 1 day of a lot of traffic. And you really have no idea how that's going to manifest over time; you can't really know which way your pendulum is swinging unless you ARE actually recording 100% of the traffic to begin with.  The affect of all this is that it will absolutely destroy your trended data, which is the core principle of making any kind of meaningful analysis.

So basically, if you really want to reliably output tracking to a % of traffic, you will need a mechanism in place that does in fact record 100% of traffic. If I were going to roll my own homebrewed "sampler", I would do this:

In either a flatfile or a database table I would have two columns, one representing "yes", one representing "no".  And each time a request is made, I look for the cookie. If the cookie does NOT exist, I count this as a new visitor. Since it is a new visitor, I will increment one of those columns by 1.

Which one? It depends on what percent of traffic I am wanting to (not) track. In this example, we're doing a very simple 50/50 split, so really, all I need to do is increment whichever one is lower, and in the case that they are currently both equal, I can pick one at random.  If you want to do a more uneven split, e.g. 30% tracked, 70% not tracked, then the formula becomes a bit more complex. But that's a different topic for discussion ( *also, there are a lot of papers and documents and wikis out there published by people a lot smarter than me that can explain it a lot better than me!* ).

Then, if it is fated that that I incremented the "yes" column, I set the "track" cookie to "yes".  Otherwise I set the "track" cookie to "no".

Then in in my controller (or bootstrap, router, whatever all requests go through), I would look for the cookie called "track" and see if it has a value of "yes" or "no". If "yes" then I output the tracking script. If "no" then I do not.

So in summary, process would be:

- Request is made
- Look for cookie.
- If cookie is not set, update database/flatfile incrementing either yes or no.
- Set cookie with yes or no.
- If cookie is set to yes, output tracking
- If cookie is set to no, don't output tracking

**Note:** Depending on language/technology of your server, cookie won't actually be set until next request, so you may need to throw in logic to look for a returned value from db/flatfile update, then fallback to looking for cookie value in last 2 steps.

**Another (more general) note:** In general, you should beware sampling. It is true that some tracking tools (most notably Google Analytics) samples data. But the thing is, it initially records *all* of the data, and then uses complex algorithms to sample from there, including *excluding/exempting* certain key metrics from being sampled (like purchases, goals, etc.).

Just think about that for a minute. Even if you take the time to setup a proper "sampler" as described above, you are basically throwing out the window data proving people are doing key things on your site - the important things that help you decide where to go as far as giving visitors a better experience on your site, etc..so now the only way around it is to start recording everything internally and factoring those things in to whether or not to send the data to AA.

But all that aside.. Look, I will agree that hits are something to be concerned about on some level. I've worked with very, very large clients with effectively unlimited budgets, and even they worry about hit costs racking up.

But the bottom line is you are paying for an *enterprise level* tool. If you are concerned about the cost from Adobe Analytics as far as your site traffic.. maybe you should consider moving away from Adobe Analytics, and towards a different tool like GA, or some other tool that doesn't charge by the hit.  Adobe Analytics is an *enterprise level* tool that offers a lot more than most other tools, and it is priced accordingly. No offense, but IMO that's like leasing a Mercedes and then cheaping out on the quality of gasoline you use.

Comment: We have a file that we use as a boot strap file to serve the DTM file. What I think we are going to do is use some JS logic and cookies around that to determine if a visitor should be served the DTM code.

Comment: @MichaelJohns actually I ended up updating my answer to respond to you since I had a lot more to say than could feasibly be said in a comment. Long story short is what you want to do can't be done with javascript/cookies alone.